# Can Query results be put onto a text field of a winform in c#?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

i want to retrieve a field say email from a student database and then i want to print the information retrieved from the database inside a textbox in a windows form (in c#)...is it possible to do so.....

Comment: Yes, it is. what have you tried?

Comment: i can't think of a way to retrieve that's why i asked question..

Comment: please help.....need it urgently for my project.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What type of database are you retrieving from?  I'm assuming SQL Server 7+?  If thats the case then use the SqlConnection like so:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NameOfConnectionInAppConfigFile"].ConnectionString);
```

From here you can build your command like so:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select [email] from [DBname]",connection);
```

You now need to execute the command to get the data into a useable format.  I would use a SqlDataAdapter here to get all the information into a DataTable (You can use a SqlDataReader as well depending on what you're trying to do).  It would look like so:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
adpt.Fill(dt);
```

This now give you access to the data via DataColumn and DataRow.  From there you would reference what you are looking for and populate the textbox.  It would look something like this:

```
textBox.Text = dt.Rows[0]["email"].ToString();
```

Also stated, you need to take into account that you could have multiple emails returned.  In this case you would need to do something like this:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
     //Logic Here
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Good answer. I noticed that the part where you set the textbox text looks a little off. Maybe it should be more like textbox.Text = dt.Rows[0]["email"].ToString(). Also, the final implementation might need to consider what to do when more than 1 row is returned, if applicable?

Comment: Thanks for the correction.  I edited my answer to change the textbox population and gave an example of how to spin through the rows of the table.  :)